# how to access previous record without using LAG function

Tags: sql, oracle

How to access the previous record without using LAG() function
- calculate the diff
- find the %age increase or decrease

This is what i have tried for finding the difference

```
WITH test AS
(
    SELECT rownum rn, quantity 
    FROM test1
)
SELECT  cur.quantity - previous.quantity as diff
FROM test cur
JOIN test previous
ON cur.Rn - 1 = previous.Rn;
```

but not able to consolidate ..

INPUT

```
TEST1
s_id  quantity
11        50
21        55
31        65
41        55
51        75
61        75
71        85
81        80
91        90
```

Expected Output

```
s_id    quantity       diff    percentage_increase_decrease
11        50            0
21        55            5
31        65            10
41        55           -10
51        75            20
61        75            0
71        85            10
81        80            -5
91        90            10
```

I am getting the desired output using LAG(), but without using LAG() how to achieve the same ??
**How to calculate the 4th column in expected output i.e percentage_increase_decrease for each store id??**

Comment: Please list all the prohibited functions. Row_number() ?

Comment: Yes, and also any particular reason why they should not be used

Comment: I need to calculate the percentage  increase/decrease for each store id, please look at expected output (4th column)

Comment: What is your Oracle version? In 12.1 and higher you can probably use `match_recognize`. But first things first: **why WITHOUT using `LAG()`**? That makes no sense - what functions to use or not use is part of the solution, it is not part of the problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor modification in your query should work.

```
WITH test AS
(SELECT S_ID, QUANTITY, ROWNUM RN FROM
    (SELECT s_id, quantity 
    FROM test1 order by s_id) -- added order by before taking rownum
)
SELECT  S_ID, cur.quantity - COALESCE(previous.quantity,0) as diff -- used coalesce to avoid first row issue
FROM test cur
LEFT JOIN test previous -- used LEFT JOIN to avoid first row issue
ON cur.Rn - 1 = previous.Rn;
```

Cheers!!

**-- UPDATE --**

```
WITH test AS
(SELECT S_ID, QUANTITY, ROWNUM RN FROM
    (SELECT s_id, quantity 
    FROM test1 order by s_id) -- added order by before taking rownum
)
SELECT
    S_ID,
    QUANTITY,
    QUANTITY - PREV_QUANTITY AS DIFF,
    CASE WHEN PREV_QUANTITY <> 0 THEN
      ROUND((QUANTITY - PREV_QUANTITY) * 100 / PREV_QUANTITY, 2)
    ELSE
      100 -- IF PREV_QUANTITY IS 0 OR NULL THEN WE CAN TAKE 100 AS  PERCENTAGE OR 0 OR ANY OTHER VALUE YOU WANT
    END AS PERCENTAGE_INCREASE_DECREASE
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            S_ID,
            CUR.QUANTITY,
            COALESCE(PREVIOUS.QUANTITY, 0) AS PREV_QUANTITY  -- used coalesce to avoid first row issue
        FROM
            TEST CUR
            LEFT JOIN TEST PREVIOUS -- used LEFT JOIN to avoid first row issue
             ON CUR.RN - 1 = PREVIOUS.RN
    );
```

Cheers!!

Comment: How to calculate the 4th column in expected output i.e percentage_increase_decrease for each store id??

Comment: See the updated section to calculate the 4th column

Comment: getting this error "divisor is equal to zero" . do we need to use decode or case ??

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
SELECT cur.s_id 
      ,cur.quantity 
      ,(curr.quantity - NVL(
                           (select b.quantity
                              from test b
                             where b.s_id =(select max(a.sid)
                                              from test a
                                             where a.s_id<cur.s_id
                                            )
                            ),0) 
  FROM test cur
```

Comment: How to calculate the 4th column in expected output i.e percentage_increase_decrease for each store id??

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can't use `lag()`, use `min()` or `max()`:

```
select t.*,
       (quantity - min(quantity) over (order by id rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding)
       ) as diff
from test1;
```

Comment: How to calculate the 4th column in expected output i.e percentage_increase_decrease for each store id??    without using any function, can we achieve the same ??